Fairly new computer, windows 10 pro, not able to open cmd in a specific path by typing cmd in the address bar of file explorer
I used to be able to do this on my laptop. But now I have a desktop and when I try this, it just shows C:\>
instead of being in the path I want it to be in. I have no idea how to fix this or where to even begin. I couldn't find anything where someone had this exact same issue, but something similar where cmd did not work at all.
I tried doing "cd C:\Users\me\Desktop\path.zip\path and as I was typing this I realized the problem. I didn't realize I was working in a ZIP folder. So I simply extracted all and it started working. Feel pretty dumb about it but that solves my problem.

yeah thats one of the many awkward situations created by the way MS implemented its integrated zip functionality in windows. Don't get me wrong, its good to have that capability, but it does come with some compromises, like things that appear to be directories to the user, but that in fact are not.

If you already submitted the question, and then found your answer, you should answer your own question with an answer, not edit the question adding the answer to the question. As it is, the question and answer format of this site does not work. Additional answers can't be posted. The question is not a question.

I tried doing "cd C:\Users\me\Desktop\path.zip\path and as I was typing this I realized the problem. I didn't realize I was working in a ZIP folder. So I simply extracted all and it started working. Feel pretty dumb about it but that solves my problem.

happen to everyone
